# Add user to SSH - connection with file

Tags: server, permissions, ssh

I have a server Ubuntu 16 with 2 users (aaa, bbb). By default, I can access the server using this line:

```
ssh -i /home/some_user/PEM_Keys/key.pem aaa@127.0.0.0
```

Now, I need to be able to connect by using the bbb user:

```
ssh -i /home/some_user/PEM_Keys/key.pem bbb@127.0.0.0
```

I've tried doing those commands, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
mkdir /home/bbb/.ssh
mkdir /home/bbb/.ssh/authorized_keys
sudo chown -R "bbb:bbb" /home/bbb/.ssh
sudo chmod 0700 /home/bbb/.ssh
sudo chmod 0600 /home/bbb/.ssh/authorized_keys
sudo cp /home/aaa/.ssh/authorized_keys /home/bbb/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

The pem file that I'm using cannot be generated for the bbb user.

Any ideas?

----------------- Edit --------------

```
grep bbb /etc/passwd -> bbb:x:1001:1001::/home/bbb:/bin/bash
id bbb -> uid=1001(bbb) gid=1001(bbb) groups=1001(bbb)
```

Comment: Did you really create the user `bbb`? Check with `grep bbb /etc/passwd` or `id bbb`...

Comment: @FedonKadifeli What should I look for with those commands?

Comment: @FedonKadifeli Could you please review my **[edits](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1152347/revisions)** and also review the [editing help](/editing-help) to improve the readability of your own edits in the future... **;-)**

Comment: `/home/bbb/.ssh/authorized_keys` should not be a directory. Remove `/home/bbb/.ssh/authorized_keys` and try to copy the **file**  `/home/aaa/.ssh/authorized_keys`. After copying the **file** `authorized_keys` under `/home/bbb/.ssh/` **folder** you should `chown` the **file** `/home/bbb/.ssh/authorized_keys`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @FedonKadifeli:

- Remove the authorized_keys
- copy the file from aaa to bbb
- chown the bbb/.ssh

Everything is working now!